# segue loading viewcontroller but not displaying it

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have a problem displaying a View Controller when calling a segue from code in an iPad app.

I have the segue setup in IB by Ctrl dragging from one view controller to the other, with

Identifier: **viewDocumentSegue**, Style: **Modal**, Presentation: **Default**, Transition: **Default**

I'm then calling the segue from the first view controller using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewDocumentSegue" sender:nil];
```

and passing a variable to the second view controller using

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setFileURL:)]) {
        [destination setValue:fileName forKey:@"fileURL"];
    }
}
```

The second view controller does get loaded, as the NSLogs I have in **viewDidLoad viewWillAppear** and **viewDidAppear** show in the console, but nothing gets displayed.

I'm thinking the second view controller's view is somewhere in the view hierachy. But how do I force it to the top?

**Edit**

Here is a screenshot of the interface (some thing needed to be blacked out). I've added some notes explaining the structure. Hopefully it will help.

(I can't upload images yet so here's a link)
http://www.linfoots.com/Screenshot.jpg

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: iPhone or iPad? What are the relevant modal presentation and modal context settings? You say "stack" - is this all happening inside a navigation controller?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I've edited original post. It's an iPad app and I should have said view hierarchy not stack. I thought the modal presentation was handled within the Storyboard and segue frameworks. I'm new to the Storyboards so still trying to get used to them.

Comment: Okay, so now we know you're on iPad. What else? Are you in a custom parent view controller? Describe the storyboard or show a screen shot of it. No one can possibly reproduce this issue from what you've said.

Comment: thanks for your patience matt. I've now added a screen shot with some annotations of what's going on. I also took your advice of creating a new project with the relevant view controllers and UI elements to replicate the app and it worked perfectly. So I'm going to strip the app down to basics to see if I can find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing the additional info I've asked for, so it's impossible to answer your question in detail. What I suggest you do is make a completely new project with just two view controllers. Connect them in the storyboard in the same way. You will see that what you're trying to do should in fact work just fine. Once you've convinced yourself of that, you can go back and see what the difference is in the project you're having trouble with.

EDIT:

Okay, thanks for the screen shot. It looks like you're trying to use a storyboard in connection with a parent view controller, exactly as I guessed in my second comment. That's not easy because a storyboard knows nothing of your parent view controller's children. You will be much happier using multiple storyboards, or no storyboard at all.

Now we come to the problem of using a parent view controller. You didn't ask about this, but it could be at the heart of your issue. It is *crucial* that you manage child view controllers properly. See the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

You *must* do this elaborate dance every time, or things won't go right:

When a view controller is to become your parent view controller’s child:

- You call addChildViewController: on your parent view controller. The child is automatically added to the parent’s childViewControllers array, which retains it.
- You get the child view controller’s view into your interface, if that’s what adding a child view controller means.
- You send didMoveToParentViewController: to the child with the parent view controller as its argument.

When a view controller is to cease being your parent view controller’s child:

- You send willMoveToParentViewController: to the child with a nil argument.
- You remove the child view controller’s view from your interface, if that’s what removing a child view controller means.
- You send removeFromParentViewController to the child. The child is automatically removed from the parent’s childViewControllers array, which releases it.

Finally, when you do a modal transition, `definesPresentationContext` in your parent chain becomes crucial so that the modal view knows what view to replace in the interface. This downloadable example from my book demonstrates the necessary distinctions:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/tree/master/convertedToIOS5/p476containerController2

Comment: Thanks matt, this has helped a great deal. I now have an app that actually works :) Anyway due to the what seems to be overly complicated implementation of child view controllers I have removed them from the app and just display each view modally, either animated or not. In the end it has actually made the whole interface much simpler, which can only be a good thing.

I've had a look through your iOS 5 book and it seems much more comprehensive than the books I currently have and will be sure to purchase a copy when it's released.

Again thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, but of course you had to do all the work. :) To me, the most important advice I gave was, "make a simple project". I use that technique all the time, to show myself how something *should* work without the added complexity of my actual app. It's so fast and easy, yet so few people try it.

Comment: @matt It's not the place to advertise matt's book, but actually after reading roughly 50 books in iOS topics that book is far the best. It helped me to clarify the most important parts of the iOS especially the basics of the view controller concept.