# How to add a UITableView as a subview to a UIView in xib?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, xib, subview

I have a custom view that I built using `xib` file. In this custom view, there is a `UIView` where I would like to add a static `UITableView` as a subview. The `UITableView` to be shown here is present on the `storyboard` and associated to a `UITableViewController`. I did the following:

```
let vc = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil))
    .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableController") as! TableController
vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
table = vc.table // this is an outlet, I'm sure it is not nil
table.delegate = vc
table.dataSource = vc
table.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
containerView.addSubview(table)
```

I can see the green background on my custom view but the table cells are not being displayed

[image: no table cells!]
I know the outlet to the table is not nil because when debugging if I inspect the `table` variable using the `Quick Look` icon below the console, I can see the table.

**UPDATE**

I realized my approach was not a good one.

I achieved the results I wanted by making my View a subview of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and programmatically creating a `UITable` and a required `TableViewCell`. Crazy amounts of codes!!

Answer (score 1):

> The UITableView to be shown here is present on the storyboard and associated to a UITableViewController.

In that case, what you're doing is totally illegal and that's why it isn't working. You cannot just call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, grab the view controller's view, and stuff that view into the interface with `addSubview`.

After all, think about it: if you do that, *what happens to the view controller*? It goes out of existence, and you've got a totally nonfunctional view.

There is a rigorous dance that you are required to do in order to make the TableController a *child view controller* of `self` (the current view controller — and you are not doing the dance.

Comment: For details of the dance, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746580/341994 That was back in 2012 but the rules have not changed at all. Follow them. — Here it is demonstrated in modern-day Swift: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p316containerController/ch19p631containerController/ViewController.swift

Comment: Is there any other way that I can access that UITableView? I can't find container view in xib file so I had to resort to this madness. As you can see, I'm terribly desperate to get this done.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "any other way". What I am suggesting is easy. I've shown you the code. Why not just do it? You only need to add a couple of lines of code to what you already have.

Comment: I have only one view controller, that's UITableViewController. The view I want to embed this table in is in a xib file whose owner is a UIView subclass. So actually there is no parent view controller. There's just parent view. By "any other way" I meant any other approaches or hacks

Comment: Then you _need_ another view controller. If you "embed this table" into a "view", that view belongs to some view controller. Well, _that_ view controller cannot be the table view controller; the table view controller owns the _table_ and nothing else. Therefore there have to be two view controllers in this story, and they have to be in proper parent-child relationship as I said in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, your links are really helpful. But I realize my approach is hopelessly wrong.